# Node server - add a 'createdBy' property to data

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to add a 'createdBy' property to my 'lab-swaps' data and fill it with the current accounts email.

In the 'create' function on the lab-swap service on the server, I tried to add the account data, but the 'email' is always 'undefined' in the console. I'm probably not using the correct syntax, or not sending the "account" information from the Angular front-end?

(Front-end)lab-swap.service.ts:

```
    create(params: any, account: Account) { //do I need "account" here?
        return this.http.post(baseUrl, params);  
    }
```

(Back-end)lab-swap.service.js:

```
async function create(account, params) { //do I need "account" here?
    const labSwap = new db.LabSwap(account, params);
    labSwap.verified = Date.now();
    labSwap.createdBy = this.account.email; //whats correct syntax to use?

    // save labSwap table
    await labSwap.save();

}
```

lab-swap.controller.js:

```
function create(req, res, next) {
    labSwapService.create(req.body)
        .then(() => res.json({ message: 'Lab Swap created' }))
        .catch(next);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by just adding a new field to the front-end form and set the account email from there:

```
createdBy: [this.account.email],
```